# MIMEMultipart ['From'] is not working, what is the problem?

Tags: python, email, smtplib, mimemultipart

I'm trying to send an email attachment using
`MIMEMultipart ['From']` and it is not working, what is the problem?

When I run the code, it says this:

```
n send_email
    msg['From'] = from_address
    ~~~^^^^^^^^                                                                                 ule>
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

```py
def send_email(filename, attachment, to_address):
    from_address = email_address 
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = from_address
    msg['To'] = to_address
    msg['Subject'] = "Log File"
    body = "Body_of_the_mail"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    filename = filename
    attachment = open(attachment, "rb")
    p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    p.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(p)
    p.add_header('Content_Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)
    msg.attach(p)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(from_address, password)
    text = msg.as_string()
    s.sendmail(from_address, to_address, text)
    s.quit()

send_email(keys_information, file_path + extend + keys_information, to_address)
```

Comment: You are not creating an instance, but trying to set attributes in the class. Use `MIMEMultipart()`.